# Symfony read only checkbox checked

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

I'm looking for a way to disable text input validation and readOnly the TextType if the box is checked?

```
$formBuilder
            ->add('text',      TextType::class,array(
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank()
            )))
            ->add('box',      CheckboxType::class, array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => 'Box'
            ))

    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an `eventListener` to your formBuilder and add constraints based on input data.  Read more about dynamic form modification [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).

Not tested but maybe something like this:

```php
$formBuilder->add('text', ...);
$formBuilder->add('box', ...);

$formBuilder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
   $data = $event->getData();
   $form = $event->getForm();

   if (isset($data["box"])) {  // Or use something like $data->getBox() if you are using objects
      $formBuilder->add('text', ...); // Replace field without constraints
   }
   
});
```

Keep in mind that this will only do server side validation, not frontend.